# Column View right click doesn't always work

Tags: pantheon-files

I like using the column view but i usually want to open a folder to see something or maybe edit the properties of the folder after i open it but if i right click the opened folder, the menu does not appear until i click the back button to go back to the directory where the folder is located and then right click on the desired folder, am i missing something or is this just a bug? I'm on eOS Juno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a duplicate of this bug:
https://github.com/elementary/files/issues/602

A fix for this has already been submitted for review, approval and merging.  Hopefully it will be fixed in the released version soon.

Comment: Thank you very much, will patiently await the release.